# Espera en consumo de webservice

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas, async-await

Necesito consumir un webservice via node.js y no tengo nada de experiencia. Vi que trabaja en forma asincrónica, pero no logro darme cuenta como adaptar mi codigo mediante Promesas o async/await

Va mi codigo:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

  }
  body = '{"sdtAgendar":{"ClienteNombre":"bruno","ClienteCel":"09999999","ClienteMail":"bruno.camar@gmail.com","AgendaDefId":1,"EmpresaId":1,"Fecha":"2019-12-02","Hora":11,"Minuto":30}}'

  console.log('Inicio');
  axios.post('http://xxx/agendapptest/rest/wsagendar', body, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);

    })
    console.log('Fin');
```

La salida de este codigo es:

```
Inicio
Fin
{ sdtResultado: { Codigo: 3, Mensaje: 'AGENDA OCUPADA POR OTRO EVENTO' } }
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

y yo pretendo que que sdtResultado se imprima entre Inicio y Fin.

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan darme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de hacerlo con promesas, tendrás que meter todo el código que depende de ella dentro de la resolución de la misma (Al menos que quieras hacer una mezcla rara de promesas y async/await, o usar callbacks).

En el caso de async/await, como no veo que tu código este contenido dentro de una función, una manera seria haciendo una función que se autoinvoque.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

}
body = '{"sdtAgendar":{"ClienteNombre":"bruno","ClienteCel":"09999999","ClienteMail":"bruno.camar@gmail.com","AgendaDefId":1,"EmpresaId":1,"Fecha":"2019-12-02","Hora":11,"Minuto":30}}'

// promesas

console.log('Inicio');
axios.post('http://xxx/agendapptest/rest/wsagendar', body, {
  headers: headers
})
  .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);

  console.log('Fin');

})
  .catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);

})

// async/await 

(async () => {

  try {

    console.log('Inicio');

    const response = await axios.post('http://xxx/agendapptest/rest/wsagendar', body, {
      headers: headers
    })

    console.log(response.data);

    console.log('Fin');

  }
  catch (error) {

    console.log(error);

  }

})()
```

Comment: Ahora me gustaria escalarlo a incluirlo en una funcion que reciba el body, alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: Si esta en una funcion, no te haria falta meter el codigo en una funcion autoinvocable, simplemente haz que la funcion sea "async"